# First Normal Form

Tags: database-design, database-schema, database-normalization

Im new the doing database Design and just wanted to ask a question to see if I was on the right track. Have a sample table that needs to be broken down into 1st, 2nd, and 3rd normal form and draw the dependency diagram for each. But before any of that just wanted to check if i was even right with doing a first Normal form

[image]

Comment: It looks pretty good to 2nf. Things like education, job, department, employee should be moved into there own relations i.e. removing transitive dependencies for 3nf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is actually in 2nd Normal Form, because you moved the education data into a separate table. If you only wanted to be just 1st Normal Form, you could keep the education data in the employee table, but repeat all the employee information on the rows with different education, e.g.

```
1003    Willaker    HS  High School     1982    MKTG    Marketing   23  Sales Agent
1003    Willaker    BBA Bachelor (Bus)  1988    MKTG    Marketing   23  Sales Agent
1003    Willaker    MBA Masters (Bus)   1993    MKTG    Marketing   23  Sales Agent
```

1st Normal Form is not very interesting, becaue of all this repetition; when we normalize, we almost always start with 2nd Normal Form, as you did.

Third Normal Form would remove the redundancy of having both Education Code and Education Description in the Education table, and Department Code and Department Name in the Employee table. Since the Department Name is always the same for a particular Department Code, you should have a Departments table that contains this relationship (`MKTG => Marketing`), and just put the code (or an ID) in the Employee table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I Did have it done the way you had it originally but after doing a some research seemed people would take data and of course put it into a separate table. Nice to have A solid answer. Again thank you